# "I will guess your age" game not working properly

Tags: java

I tried to make a really simple "I will guess your age" game. When I say that I haven't had birthday this year, it works just fine, but when I say that I had birthday this year, it does the same thing as when I say I didn't. For example, when i say that i was born in 2000 and say that i haven't had birthday this year, it would say that I'm 19 years old, which is correct. But when I say that I had birhday this year, it also says that I'm 19, which is, obviosly, not correct. Can someone please tell me where is the problem? Any help would be appreciated, thanks. :)

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class kouzlo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int currentyear = 2020;
        System.out.println ("Welcome! I can guess your age. What year were you born?");
        int yearofbirth = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("Have you had your birthday this year?");
        boolean yes, Yes, YES, y, Y = true;
        boolean no, No, NO, n, N = false;
        boolean hadbirthday = scanner.hasNextBoolean();
        int summary = currentyear - yearofbirth;
        int summary2 = currentyear - yearofbirth - 1;
        if (hadbirthday == true) {
            System.out.println("You're " + summary + " years old!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You're " + summary2 + " years old!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too general. What is your error? Or what exactly doesnt work? Use that as a title

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Generally questions should be as specific as possible. Describe what you think the game should do, and what it actually does,

Comment: `hadbirthday` tells you if a boolean has been read from the standard input, not whether it read `true` or `false`. For that you need [`nextBoolean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextBoolean())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the comment of Federico is right. You need to do something like:

```
boolean hadbirthday = false;

if (scanner.hasNextBoolean()) {
  boolean hadbirthday = scanner.nextBoolean();
};
```

I also see these lines:

```
boolean yes, Yes, YES, y, Y = true;

boolean no, No, NO, n, N = false;
```

which seems to be useless. If you want to allow the user to enter one of those and interpret it as a boolean, you will have to use hasNext() / next() and check if the resulting string matches one of your patterns.